# Site search for small, local website

Tags: java, spring, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm currently developing a small website in Java using Spring Boot and would like to implement a simple site search feature.

Usually, I would just search the underlying SQL database with a LIKE query, but the design of the website means that I would have to search through a lot of tables and columns. It would take quite a bit of work to implement this.

I would rather just have a webcrawler crawl through the website (every page is reachable from the root by links), and then build a index from that. The website is only accessible locally, and thus I cannot use Google Custom Search or anything like it.

The problem is that I cannot find any libraries that fits the scale of this. One option is using Nutch with Solr, but that means I have to set up a dedicated Solr server for my small website. I also cannot find any documentation on how to execute Nutch from Java without requiring a huge Hadoop dependency, which seems like overkill for such a small website.

The current solutions I have found just seems unnecessarily complex for my rather simple use case. Are there any less complex libraries/technologies that could better fit my use case?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j

Comment: @TheDarknessBeckons That seems like a much better fit than Nutch. And from what I can see, it also allows me to easily get the text of the HTML document. I could use this to build a local Lucene index at startup. This would keep the whole thing self-contained.

Comment: Mike, I have used Nutch and Solr but I haven't used crawler4j to be honest. It does seem to have quite a bit of take up though and definitely looks a lighter option. Good luck.